# Videos in shared photostream not playing

Tags: ios, photo-stream

I have a shared photostream with 7 people subscribing to photos. Now that iOS 7 is out, I was eager to try and share a video. I captured one using my phone and edited in iMovie on the phone, exported to camera roll in 720p and then put it on my shared photostream.

I can play the video from my iPhone that uploaded it, but not from my iPad. There's just a spinner that never disappears. My subscribers have the same issue, regardless of phone/iPad.

The clip is 18 seconds long, by the way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: +1. Sad really. Youre supposed to be able to upload 5 mins of 720p i think. Its just the same for me as for you. Br
RIWA

Comment: I've filed a bug report with Apple, you should too! http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Comment: Sorry. Same issue here. Strangely I have one subscriber who can view on her ipad but don't know what makes her special!